# Update a Lead from a field in Accounts using Flows

Tags: flow, process-builder

I am trying out the Flows and process builder for the first time. I am impressed with what ever i have seen till now.

Here is the use case i am trying to achieve.
When a lead is created, i want to check if there is an account existing for this lead. I am for test purposes matching if the leads email domain matches the accounts website domain. If there is a match then i want to assign the owner of the Account as the lead's owner. If there is a more than one Accounts matching then assign with owner of latest modified Account

What i did

I created a Fastlookup for lead and used the variable passed from the process builder to get the lead and assign it to a sobject variable called `{!LeadRecord}`. I created another fastlookup called AccountLookup to check if there exists and account with the website domain equals leads email domain. I have a formulae fields in account and leads for email domain and website domain.

The question that i had was how to check if the AccountLookup has any values? I did create decision component. But not sure how i can check if an account exists with a match

Comment: Just as with Apex or validation formulas, you should be able to use `!isEmpty` as a test.

Comment: Where would i give that?

Comment: Without having seen your flow, I'd expect you'd want to validate your results of your query. You could use a formula field to do that by assigning the results to the formula before going to your decision tree. If what's returned isEmpty (i.e. null), that would presumably be part of what's evaluated in your decision tree.